# How to tell if a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, button, if-statement

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changestate()
{
    var StateTextBox = document.getElementById("State");
    var IgnoreTextBox = document.getElementById("Ignore");
    var PlayButton = document.getElementById("Play");
    if(document.getElementById("Play").onclick == true)
    {
        StateTextBox.value = "Happy";   
    }
}
</script>
<input TYPE="button" VALUE="Play with Pogo" id="Play" onClick="changestate();"/>
```

I'm trying to know when the button is clicked, and have that if button is clicked in the if statement. I want to know this so I can change the value that is inside the text box. The problem is, I do not know how to tell when the button is clicked. If you could help me out that would be great.

Comment: if that function is called, then the button has been clicked. however, note that generally button inputs in a form will SUBMIT the form, which kills any js code

Comment: What are you trying to do? You appear to be checking if the `ignoreTextBox` was clicked (in both your `if` condition, and your `else` condition), rather than a button.

Comment: Youre right....let me fix it real quick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `onclick` attribute identifies what should happen when the user clicks this particular element. In your case, you're asking that a function be ran; when the function runs, you can rest assured that the button was clicked - that is after all how the function itself got put into motion (unless you invoked it some other way).

Your code is a bit confusing, but suppose you had two buttons and you wanted to know which one was clicked, informing the user via the `stateTextBox` value:

```js
(function () {
    // Enables stricter rules for JavaScript
    "use strict";
    // Reference two buttons, and a textbox
    var playButton = document.getElementById("play"),
        stateTextBox = document.getElementById("state"),
        ignoreButton = document.getElementById("ignore");
    // Function that changes the value of our stateTextBox
    function changeState(event) {
        stateTextBox.value = event.target.id + " was clicked";
    }
    // Event handlers for when we click on a button
    playButton.addEventListener("click", changeState, false);
    ignoreButton.addEventListener("click", changeState, false);
}());
```

You can test this code live at http://jsfiddle.net/Y53LA/.

Note how we add event-listeners on our `playButton` and `ignoreButton`. This permits us to keep our HTML clean (no need for an `onclick` attribute). Both of these will fire off the `changeState` function anytime the user clicks on them.

Within the `changeState` function we have access to an `event` object. This gives us some details about the particular event that took place (in this case, the `click` event). Part of this object is the `target`, which is the element that was clicked. We can grab the `id` property from that element, and place it into the `value` of the `stateTextBox`.

Here is the adjusted HTML:

```html
<input type="button" value="Play with Pogo" id="play" />
<input type="text" id="state" />
<input type="button" value="Ignore with Pogo" id="ignore" />​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can know if button clicked by using a flag (true or false).

```
        var flag = false;

    window.addEventListener("load", changestate, false);

    function changestate() {

        var StateTextBox = document.getElementById("State");
        var PlayButton = document.getElementById("Play");

        PlayButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            flag = true;
        })

        PlayButton.addEventListener("click", change)

        function change() {
            if (flag) {
                StateTextBox.value = "Happy";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking back on this, many years later, you could simply do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changestate(action)
{
    var StateTextBox = document.getElementById("State");
    var IgnoreTextBox = document.getElementById("Ignore");
    var PlayButton = document.getElementById("Play");
    if(action == "Play")
    {
        StateTextBox.value = "Happy";   
    }
}
</script>
<input TYPE="button" VALUE="Play with Pogo" id="Play" onClick='changestate("Play");'/>
```